# Chrome Extension- How to get current innerText of current tab which changes by ajax request

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I want some content of an online music site in an extension popup which changes content by ajax request for every change, like next song, etc.

How can I get the current `innerText` in an extension popup?

The site is loading `XMLHttpRequest` after the start of each song. How can I get that URL/response in the popup?

I tried by this JavaScript code but couldn't get it:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
xhr.open('GET','https://example.com/',true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {  
  if (xhr.readystate == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {  
    alert(xhr.responseText);  
  }  
  else
    alert(xhr.status);
}  
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the site is making XMLHttpRequests doesn't help you. You yourself won't be able to make the same request without knowing the data it's sending.

You'll need to inject a [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) into the webpage, and that script will be able to read the innerText of the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from a typo in `alert(xhr.responseText)`;  (you are missing a p), your code looks correct.

If that doesn't work you might be having problems having status 200 on your request. Check the [network panel of Chrome's developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) to make sure the problem isn't on the request.